# Conversão de Valor InFixo para PosFixo

Tags: javascript

Tenho que converter um valor InFixo para PosFixo

Exemplos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema do meu algoritmo é justamente nessa última linha.... acredito que o problema seja em expressões com + de 2 termos dentro do parenteses, do tipo: (X * Y + Z)

Honestamente, já debuguei o código diversas vezes, mudei pra várias versões e ainda não consegui arrumar..... alguma sugestão?

SEGUE ABAIXO O CÓDIGO COMPLETO:

```
function operando(caracter){
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(regex.test(caracter)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function operador(caracter){
    var regex = /^[*+-–/^]+$/gi;
    if(regex.test(caracter)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function obterPrioridade(caracter){
    var retorno= 0;
    var regex1 = /^[+-–]+$/gi;
    var regex2 = /^[*/]+$/gi;

    if('(' == caracter){
        retorno = 1;
    }else if(regex1.test(caracter)){
        retorno = 2;
    }else if(regex2.test(caracter)){
        retorno = 3;
    }else if ('^' == caracter){
        retorno = 4;
    }
    return retorno;
}

function transformar(){
    //Converte uma expressão da forma Infixa na forma Posfixa. Segue a lógica explica anteriormente na introdução sobre expressões
    var arrayDeCaracteres = document.getElementById("expressao").value;
    var pilha = [];
    var prioridade = 0;
    var caracter = ""; var resultado = "";

    //Varre todos os elementos da expressão de entrada e, para cada elemento, verifica se é operador ou operando. Se for operando, já adicona a saída
    for(i = 0; i < arrayDeCaracteres.length; i++){
        caracter = arrayDeCaracteres.charAt(i);

        if(operando(caracter)){
            resultado += caracter;
        }else if(operador(caracter)){
            prioridade = obterPrioridade(caracter);
            aux = pilha.pop();
            prioridade2 = obterPrioridade(aux);
            //alert('Caracter: '+caracter+'\n'+prioridade+'\nAux: '+aux+'\n'+prioridade2);
            pilha.push(aux);
            if(typeof aux === 'undefined'){
            }else{
                while((pilha.length > 1) && (prioridade2 >= prioridade)){
                    resultado += pilha.pop();
                }
            }
            pilha.push(caracter);
        }else if('(' === caracter){
            //Insere o objeto no topo da pilha
            pilha.push(caracter);
        }else if(')' === caracter){
            var item = pilha.pop();
            while ((item != '(') && (item != undefined)){
                resultado += item;
                //Recupera e remove o objeto do topo da pilha
                item = pilha.pop();
            }
        }
    }

    while(pilha.length > 1){
        resultado += pilha.pop();
    }

    console.log(resultado);
}
```

Acredito que o erro da lógica esteja nesse trecho:

```
        }else if(')' === caracter){
            var item = pilha.pop();
            while ((item != '(') && (item != undefined)){
                resultado += item;
                //Recupera e remove o objeto do topo da pilha
                item = pilha.pop();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Não.... quero converter um valor InFixo para PosFixo, vou adicionar exemplos de valores de entrada, de saída e como está saindo

Comment: Pronto... editei @renan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É um erro bastante singelo que deixou passar. Não há nada de errado no código ou no algoritmo em si, ele funciona. O erro está nas expressões regulares.

Como bem usou na função `operando`, é possível escrever `[A-Z]` para denotar todos os caracteres entre `A` e `Z`. O problema está quando escreve algo assim: `/^[*+-–/^]+$/`.

Repare ali: `[+-–]`. Isso está capturando toda uma sequencia de caracteres entre o `+` e o `–`. A solução, nesse caso, é mover o `-` (menos) para o final, ou para o começo.

Assim: `/^[-*+–/^]+$/`. O mesmo acontece na função `obterPrioridade`.

Testei e com essa simples alteração o código funciona.

Comment: Perfeito velho, funcionou direitinho, depois de uma semana me matando kkkk